# How to have 1 controller for 2 segues in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

i have one simple question. I am building an app in Xcode 5. Part of the app is the typical login screen and the register screen and a database which stores username and password. My problem is that i don't want to write Sqlite code in both screens (in both view's controllers). What i want is to have the "databaseViewController.h and .m" controlling both the login controller and register controller. My question is : How do i do that? Im not asking for code, but short similar examples would be very helpful!. I am using storyboards if that helps too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i want is to have the "databaseViewController.h and .m" controlling both the login controller and register controller

A common approach is to move the data access stuff out of your view controllers and into a data model (that's the M in MVC) that both view controller can talk to. Your model would have method to log in, register, tell you whether the user is already registered, etc. That leaves your view controllers to do what they do best: manage their respective view graphs and deal with user input. Maybe you already have some sort of data model, in which case the user registration and login functions can just be added to it. Otherwise, have your app delegate set up your model when the app starts up and share it with the view controllers that need to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question indirectly: If your goal is simply to share code between these two screens, you may find it easier to extract that code into a separate class, like `AuthenticationManager` or something, which you then use from your two different view controllers.

One common pattern for shared service objects like this is to hang them off of your application delegate. That is, add a property (e.g. `authManager`) to `AppDelegate` and then in your view controller(s), access it as `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.authManager`.